# Paypal, Add to Cart - Can I sell a product AND a subscription at the same time?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart, paypal-subscriptions

I have a question regarding Paypal.

I have a website that I sell both products and subscriptions.  I have been unable to figure out how someone can purchase a product and a subscription at the same time through my cart.

Logically I would see this as simply two products (one with reoccurring billing), but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your question is about programming? Can you write what you have attempted so far?

Comment: My question is, has anybody ever successfully sold a product and a subscription through a cart at PayPal? Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: You question seems to be off topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: This is where PayPal told me to go, so where do you suggest I go? See this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support Also, I am a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Website Payments Standard, this would not be possible.  You can not have a regular single transaction and a subscription during the same checkout.  However, if you are using Express Checkout, PayPal Payments Pro or Payflow this is possible through using the API's.  Depending on which service you use, the flow/code would be slightly different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just for clarification, I am using the Website Payments Standard, therefore I'm assuming that I will I have to make my customer go through a single transaction twice; once for the product and another for the subscription. Right?

Comment: Yes, with Website Payments Standard you would.  You could use Express Checkout instead of standard.  This is another free service to use that does not have a monthly charge or require anything special to be activated on your account.  It's already enabled by default.

Comment: Sounds like Express Checkout might be the right solution for me. By any chance, can you tell me on what I would have to do to change from Website Payments Standard to Express Checkout? Is it easy? Also, would I have to provide my own shopping cart? Any tutorial links on Express Checkout with product(s) and/or subscription(s) would much be appreciated.

Comment: There would be alot to change, as Express Checkout is completely different than standard.  Express Checkout would use API's.  You can either write your own code, or use a 3rd party shopping carts out there, some which are free.  You can find some references at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/